# Changing left percentage if has certian percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Isotope gives the wrong percentage on a certain width so I change it with jQuery.
It works but something is going wrong in the syntax so my other code wont work.

```
function fixIsotope() { 
    if ($('.blok-categorie').css('left') == '24.9573%') {
        $('.blok-categorie').css('left') == '25%') ;
    }
    return this;
}
fixIsotope();
```

It gives me a: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) error`

Answer (score 2):

Um, you have the wrong syntax for changing it

```
function fixIsotope() { 
if ($('.blok-categorie').css('left') == '24.9573%') {
    $('.blok-categorie').css('left','25%') ;
}
return this;
}
fixIsotope();
```

---

The `==` is not an assignment operator, it just does a comparison. So, you can't use it to set a value

---

Also, you have an extra `)` at the end of the second line

Comment: I figured that one aswell but the code wont work when I put the syntax like this thats the weird part. Appreciate the answer though

Comment: I guess the problem is that jQuery wont read the % change or something like that used to have a issue like that a while ago but just dropped it.